# Push user input to array

Tags: javascript

Hi so yes this is a previous issue i have had, i have hit the books and whent back to basics adjusted a few things but im still having trouble getting the input value to push to the array can some one please help me get my head around this thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var number=["1"]
   function myFunction()
   {
    var x=document.getElementById("box");
     number.push=document.getElementById("input").value;
    x.innerHTML=number.join('<br/>'); 
   }
  </script>
 <form>
  <input id="input" type=text>
   <input type=button onclick="myFunction()" value="Add Number"/>
  </form>

 <div id="box"; style="border:1px solid black;width:150px;height:150px;overflow:auto"> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try number.push (document.getElementById("input").value) instead of number.push=document.getElementById("input").value;

Comment: thank you so much i have been on this for weeks

Answer (score 4):

Here is the mistake:

```
number.push(document.getElementById("input").value);
```

`push` is a method, not an attribute ;-)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVthL/3/)

**PS:** Why the `;` after `id="box";` ? You should fix that too..! ;-)

Comment: Does that semicolon actually matter with modern, markup-correcting browsers?

Comment: It's probably not an issue with most browsers (maybe even all!) but it's still not valid code. ;-)

Comment: Going to try with my ancient Safari.

Comment: Never said it wouldn't ;-) Lot's of things work but aren't good code! That semicolon doesn't belong there! Thanks for testing tho! Which version?

Comment: `Version 4.1.3 (4533.19.4)`. Yes I know, but I was just curious if such a little semicolon matters (in HTML, in JS or most programming languages I know it does).

Comment: Yea, it was a good idea to check! I **thought** it wouldn't but it's great to **know** it doesn't! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You were close, here's the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var number = [];

   function myFunction()
   {
     var x = document.getElementById("box");
     number.push(document.getElementById("input").value);
     x.innerHTML = number.join('<br/>'); 
   }
  </script>
 <form>
  <input id="input" type=text>
   <input type=button onclick="myFunction()" value="Add Number"/>
  </form>

 <div id="box" style="border:1px solid black;width:150px;height:150px;overflow:auto"> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>​
```